# Is there a good IntelliJ color scheme for Grails development?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have searched all over and tried a dozen color schemes for my Grails project with IntelliJ and all of them are pretty unusable. Is anyone out there using a solid color scheme that wouldn't mind sharing?

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated site for it: http://ideacolorschemes.com/shufflescheme/Groovy. I use my own scheme uploaded [here](http://ideacolorschemes.com/scheme/Rxs-CJozsL0X8EbXxdLNaHZm86A/spoonman/1.0/Groovy).

Comment: Those links are dead.